# SQL select to display corresponding value of a column in another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

```
RID|value|
=========
1  |$100 |
2  |$200 | 
3  |$100 | 
4  |$400 |
5  |$400 | 

RID|rname|
=========
1  | T01 |
2  | W100| 
3  | D03 | 
4  | D05 |
5  | T08 |
```

I want to select RID in the first table such that i will be able to display the corresponding value of RID in the second table; so if i select RID = 2,  i want to display W100

Comment: You should try a tutorial before asking questions. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Why involve table 1 when you only want data from table 2?

Comment: Thanks FancyPants for the suggestion, the scope of the tables involved is bigger than what i can bring on to this space.; table 1 is a lot more complex than i provided. The solutions provided worked alright. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the 2 tables
you can do it with inner join when the shared column will be the number column.

for example:

```
select rname
from rid.name n 
join rid.value v 
on n.shared_column = v.shared_column
```

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT b.RID, rname,
FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.RID = b.RID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t2.rname AS Name
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.RID = t2.RID
```